# What is the optimal strategy?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

There are $m+n+1$ cards numbered $1,2,\ldots m+n+1$. Participants A and B respectively get $m$ and $n$ cards. Meanwhile, they only know what they get. The remaining card is face down on the desk. Starting with A, participants A and B take turns doing one of the following:

1. Say a number. If the other participant has the card, he should show the card.
2. Guess the remaining 1 card. If it is correct, the participant wins, otherwise he loses. In both cases, end the game.

> What is the optimal strategy for each participant? What is the probability of each participant to win the game?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Could you tell us how you have tried to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't get the game. Say A starts and did steps $1$ and $2$ than he is going to win or lose and game ends. So B couldn't start game. There should be a bypass option. If you have to guess than there is no role for B.

Comment: I am glad to see you.I think we should take some particular example just like m=n=1 then ues the mathematical induction.

Comment: @M.Vinay Thanks for correcting my question.

Comment: @user64066 No, the game doesn't end if A does Step 1. I suppose you misunderstood the statement "In both cases, end the game" in Step 2. That is only for Step 2, and the two cases are either the player guessed the remaining card correctly and won, or he lost.

Comment: @user64066 In every turn ,the participant can only chose and make one step,not both two steps.

Comment: I think there is a problem: if I call a number and my opponent does not have it then that is the hidden card (assuming I do not call one of my own or a previously called one and n and m are known). But now it is my opponents turn and he can correctly guess the hidden card. So I've done all the work for him.